# Which design pattern is the opposite of the Assembler pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-object

As I understand it, an Assembler is a design pattern used to convert a domain object to a DTO.

What would you call the design pattern that is used to convert a DTO to a domain object ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Data Transfer Object* is the (P of EAA) design pattern. Assembler is just a name given to one of its components.

I think you could use the term Assembler when going in either direction (another common term is *Mapper*). Or you could say Assembler for domain object -> DTO, and **Disassember** for DTO -> domain object.